# Reusing hibernateTemplate object can cause resource/memory leak?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, memory-leaks, spring-orm

I am using Spring ORM support for implementing some RESTFul web services in my application. The application is stopping to respond after a few hours. I am suspecting a resource leak.

I have code similar to this:

```
protected Session getSession() {
   Session session = null;
   try {
        session = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
       } catch (Exception ex) {}
     if (session == null) {
        session = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().openSession();
       }
        return session;
      }    
    .....

public void someMethod(){
   Session session = null;
   try {
        session = getSession();
       } catch (Exception ex) {}
       query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);
       List<Object[]> myObjs= (List<Object[]>) query.list();
       ....
       ....
       Query query2 = session.createSQLQuery(queryString2);
       BigInteger count = (BigInteger) query2.uniqueResult();
      }
    catch(Exception e){}
```

I am reusing the session object to execute query as well as query2. Can reusing the session object result in a resource leak?

Comment: After an exception occurs the session is not usable any more (in an undefined state according to the docs) and your application could block at the next request. An increase in memory consumption could be due to L1 caching. Why aren't you using the common best practices for hibernate with spring?

Comment: Do not use HibernateTemplate. it has been deprecated long time ago, you can use Hibernate's Session, it integrates very well with Spring.